# Trying to read quicktime file chapter metadata

Tags: php, python, linux, perl, quicktime

Does anyone know of a way using php, perl, or python I can read the chapter name and chapter start time from a quicktime video file in a .mov container on a linux system?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the unix commandline [`extract`](http://www.gnunet.org/libextractor/) tool which supports hundreds of file formats - `.mov` included.

Comment: I tried using libextractor. It didn't list the chapter information though. Thanks for the suggestion.